# Thread safe queue with fixed size

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, queue, buffer

what I want to do is to push integers to my threadSafe queue implementation with multiple threads and concurrently with another series of threads pop away the inserted numbers. All of this operation has to be thread safe, but another option that I want to have is that the size of the queue must be fixed, just like a buffer. If the buffer is full all the push threads must wait the pop threads to free some slot.

This is my implementation of the queue/buffer, it seems to work but after few iterations it stops and remains blocked without any error.

```
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>

class Queue
{
private:
    std::queue<T> queue_;
    std::mutex mutex_;
    std::condition_variable cond_;

public:

    T pop()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mutex_);

        cond_.wait(mlock, [this]{return !queue_.empty();});

        auto val = queue_.front();
        queue_.pop();
        return val;
    }

    void pop(T& item)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mutex_);

        cond_.wait(mlock, [this]{return !queue_.empty();});

        item = queue_.front();
        queue_.pop();
    }

    void push(const T& item, int buffer)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mutex_);

        while (queue_.size() >= buffer)
        {
            cond_.wait(mlock);
        }

        queue_.push(item);
        mlock.unlock();
        cond_.notify_one();
    }

    Queue()=default;
    Queue(const Queue&) = delete;            // disable copying
    Queue& operator=(const Queue&) = delete; // disable assignment

};
```

The size of the buffer is defined in the push function with the variable buffer. This is an example of usage:

```
 void prepare(Queue<int>& loaded, int buffer, int num_frames)
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < num_frames; i++)
     {
         cout<< "push "<<i<<endl;
         loaded.push(i, buffer);
     }
 }

 void load (vector<Frame>& movie, Queue<int>& loaded, int num_frames,
                            int num_points, int buffer, int height, int width)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < num_frames; i++)
        {
            int num = loaded.pop();
            cout<< "pop "<<num<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int num_threadsXstage = 4;

    int width = 500;
    int height = 500;

    int num_points = width * height;

    int num_frames = 100;

    int frames_thread = num_frames/num_threadsXstage;

    int preset = 3;

    int buffer = 10;

    //Vectors of threads
    vector<thread> loader;

    //Final vector
    vector<Frame> movie;
    movie.resize(num_frames);

    //Working queues
    Queue<int> loaded;

    //Prepare loading queue task
    thread preparator(prepare, ref(loaded), buffer, num_frames);

    for (int i = 0; i < num_threadsXstage; i++)
    {
        //stage 1
        loader.push_back(thread(&load, ref(movie), ref(loaded), frames_thread,
                                num_points, buffer, height, width));

    }


    // JOIN
    preparator.join();

    join_all(loader);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are missing a `notify()` in the `pop()` to signal the `push()` it's clear to push now. Also, as pointed out already, you need to keep holding the lock while notifying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `pop` functions could allow a thread waiting to `push` to make forward progress, but they don't call any `notify` function. You must call the appropriate `notify` function any time you may make it possible for a thread blocked on the condition variable to make forward progress.

Although it's quite complex to explain why, you should either call `notify_all` or call `notify_one` while still holding the lock. It is theoretically possible to "wake the wrong thread" otherwise because you are using the same condition variable for two predicates (the queue is not empty and the queue is not full).

To avoid very hard to understand failure modes, always do one of these three things:

1. Do not use the same condition variable to handle more than one predicate. For example, use one condition variable for "not empty" and another for "not full";
2. Always use `notify_all`, never `notify_one`; or
3. Always call notify functions while holding the mutex.

So long as you follow at least one of these three rules, you will avoid an obscure failure mode where you wake only a thread that chose to sleep after you released the mutex while leaving the only thread that could handle the condition still blocked.

Comment: Ok, thanks, sorry but I'm quite new to multithreading and condition variables, I don't fully understand how I can modify my code, and which of this three things is more suitable for my problem.

Comment: @CIVI89 The most important thing is to call a notify function when you pop. That will fix the problem that caused you to ask this question. As for which of the three methods to use, any of them will work fine in your case. You could use two condition variables, always signal while holding the lock, or call notify_all every time. Any one of those three things will fix the rare race condition you'll probably never actually hit. ;)

Comment: If you signal the condition variable while not holding the lock, the signal can get lost when it happens to be sent between the check of the predicate and the wait operation on the condition variable. The is independent of using multiple condition variables or using `notify_all` over `notify_one`. Or am I missing something? I thought that was the point of associating wait operations with locks.

Comment: @TFM There is no harm in losing the signal in that case because the thread won't wait. It will check the predicate, see that it does not need to wait, and not wait. The signal is only precious if a thread is waiting, and that thread would have to have seen the predicate before we changed it. And we needed the lock to change it, so it must have already released it. Hence it's already waiting and cannot miss the signal. (But as I said in my answer, this is very hard to understand. So just follow one of the three rules and you need not worry.)

Comment: @TFM Think about it. All you do by unlocking before signalling is signal later. Any thread that was waiting when you held the lock will still be waiting later unless it gets woken up anyway. The only way waiting to signal can break something is if you signal the "wrong thread", one that only started waiting after you released the lock. And any of the three rules will avoid this problem.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes, of course, I was confused. It is the predicate the needs to be protected, not the condition variable.